# How to create an area?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.JDOMException;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;

public class ReadXMLFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {

  SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
  File xmlFile = new File("c:\\test.xml");

  try {

    Document document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
    Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
    List list = rootNode.getChildren("raum");

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

       Element node = (Element) list.get(i);

       System.out.println("ID : " + node.getChildText("ID"));

    }

  } catch (IOException io) {
    System.out.println(io.getMessage());
  } catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
    System.out.println(jdomex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

}

I don't understand how the step in between has to look like in order to insert the imported coordinates into the polygon.. Maybe someone can help me with this?

Comment: Actually, I think SAX parsing is more suitable to your situation. Do you have to use JDOM ?

Comment: I don't understand the recommendations to avoid JDOM. It's a nice library with a very clean API, much friendlier than the "standard" XML parsing API.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use Jdom.. I changed the question to make clear what exactly I don't get..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness?
This is how to achieve it using SAX parser.
Note that it is not clear to me, from your question, which `Polygon` you are referring to. I presume it is a java class. It can't be [`java.awt.Polygon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) because its points are all `int` whereas your sample XML file contains only `double` values. The only other class I thought of was [`javafx.scene.shape.Polygon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Polygon.html) that contains an array of points where each point is a `double`. Hence in the below code, I create an instance of `javafx.scene.shape.Polygon`.

For the situation you describe in your question, I don't see the point (no pun intended) in loading the entire DOM tree into memory. You simply need to create a point every time you encounter a *x* and a *y* coordinate in the XML file and add those coordinates to a collection of points.

Here is the code. Note that I created an XML file named *polygon0.xml* that contains the entire XML from your question. Also note that you can extend class [`org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) rather than implement interface `ContentHandler`.

```java
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.Locator;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

public class Polygons implements ContentHandler {
    private boolean isX;
    private boolean isY;
    private Polygon polygon;
/* Start 'ContentHandler' interface methods. */
    @Override // org.xml.sax.ContentHandler
    public void setDocumentLocator(Locator locator) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override // org.xml.sax.ContentHandler
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        polygon = new Polygon();
    }

    @Override // org.xml.sax.ContentHandler
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override // org.xml.sax.ContentHandler
    public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri) throws SAXException {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override // org.xml.sax.ContentHandler
    public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override // org.xml.sax.ContentHandler
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        isX = "x".equals(qName);
        isY = "y".equals(qName);
    }

    @Override // org.xml.sax.ContentHandler
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (isX) {
            isX = false;
        }
        if (isY) {
            isY = false;
        }
    }

    @Override // org.xml.sax.ContentHandler
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if (isX || isY) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
            int end = start + length;
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                sb.append(ch[i]);
            }
            polygon.getPoints().add(Double.parseDouble(sb.toString()));
        }
    }

    @Override // org.xml.sax.ContentHandler
    public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override // org.xml.sax.ContentHandler
    public void processingInstruction(String target, String data) throws SAXException {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override // org.xml.sax.ContentHandler
    public void skippedEntity(String name) throws SAXException {
        // Do nothing.
    }
/* End 'ContentHandler' interface methods. */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polygons instance = new Polygons();
        Path path = Paths.get("polygon0.xml");
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(path.toFile())) { // throws java.io.IOException
            SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser(); // throws javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException , org.xml.sax.SAXException
            XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader(); // throws org.xml.sax.SAXException
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(instance);
            InputSource input = new InputSource(reader);
            xmlReader.parse(input);
            System.out.println(instance.polygon);
        }
        catch (IOException                  |
               ParserConfigurationException |
               SAXException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output from running the above code:

```
Polygon[points=[400.3, 997.2, 400.3, 833.1, 509.9, 833.1, 509.9, 700.0, 242.2, 700.0, 242.2, 600.1, 111.1, 600.1, 111.1, 300.0, 300.0, 300.0, 300.0, 420.0, 600.5, 420.0, 600.5, 101.9, 717.8, 101.9, 717.8, 200.0, 876.5, 200.0, 876.5, 500.8, 1012.1, 500.8, 1012.1, 900.2, 902.0, 900.2, 902.0, 997.2], fill=0x000000ff]
```

### EDIT

As requested, by OP, here is an implementation using JDOM (version 2.0.6)

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.filter.ElementFilter;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.util.IteratorIterable;

import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

public class Polygon2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        Path path = Paths.get("polygon0.xml");
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        try {
            Document jdomDoc = builder.build(path.toFile()); // throws java.io.IOException , org.jdom2.JDOMException
            Element root = jdomDoc.getRootElement();
            IteratorIterable<Element> iter = root.getDescendants(new ElementFilter("edge"));
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Element elem = iter.next();
                Element childX = elem.getChild("x");
                polygon.getPoints().add(Double.parseDouble(childX.getText()));
                Element childY = elem.getChild("y");
                polygon.getPoints().add(Double.parseDouble(childY.getText()));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException | JDOMException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(polygon);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fabulous! Thank you for your effort! ... Just to make sure that I got it right. SAX is the alternative to Jdom or are both somehow interrelated?

Comment: SAX and [J]DOM are different ways to parse XML. There is also [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html)

Comment: Can you give me some advice how to do the whole thing with JDOM? Using javafx.scene.shape.Polygon .. Or maybe some advice for more detailed resources, because I need to use JDOM but I really don't know how to use the parsed XML to build the Polygon. Would appreciate your help a lot

Comment: @C-lara Done. See code under **EDIT** in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow any sample JDOM parser example and do it.
For example, [this](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-jdom-example/) explains how to read  the xml and take the data in a list and iterate over it. Just follow the steps and understand what you  are doing, you can easily get it done.

Answer (score 1):

You can read XML files DOM parser library check [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java) article.

I assume you are working on a Desktop application so you might want to use FileChooser for file selection. Here is an [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm) of this.

Also, I think you would need to make some structural changes (for convinience) to your XML file so that it would have something like this:

```
<xpoints>
 <x>5<x/>
...
</xpoints>
<ypoints>
 <y>5<y/>
...
</ypoints>
```

But for existing structure doing something like this would be enogh:

```
    File file = new File("file");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(file);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("edge");
// you can iterate over all edges
    for (int itr = 0; itr < nodeList.getLength(); itr++)
    {
      Node node = nodeList.item(itr);
      if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
      {
        Element eElement = (Element) node;

//then you can access values, for example, to pass them to an array
        array.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("x").item(0).getTextContent()));

      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! ... And when I pass the values to the array I can then use this array for polygon creation, right?

Comment: Yes, I used ArrayList here, but you can, of course, replace with simple arrays and pass them as arguments